# How to add header to soap fault without interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I'm trying to find a way to add header to soap fault with out using interceptor. Is there any alternative solution.

Basically I've my soap request as follows.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://kp.web.com/schema/" xmlns:sch1="http://kp.web.com/Shared/schema/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sch:clientHeader>
         <sch1:consumerId>12</sch1:consumerId>
      </sch:clientHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:addRequest>
         <sch:field1>-3</sch:field1>
         <sch:field2>-1</sch:field2>
      </sch:addRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Success message.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soap:Header>
      <serverHeader xmlns:ns2="http://kp.web.com/schema/" xmlns="http://kp.web.com/Shared/schema/">
         <ns2:consumerId>12</ns2:consumerId>
         <ns2:completionCode>100</ns2:completionCode>
      </serverHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <addResponse xmlns="http://kp.web.com/schema/" xmlns:ns2="http://kp.web.com/Shared/schema/">
         <result>-4</result>
      </addResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When fault occurs

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Faulted you sent -1 and -1</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <faultResponse xmlns:ns2="http://kp.web.com/schema/" xmlns="http://kp.web.com/Shared/schema/">400</faultResponse>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would expect fault response something like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://kp.web.com/schema/" xmlns:sch1="http://kp.web.com/Shared/schema/">
    <soap:Header>
          <serverHeader>
             <ns2:consumerId>12</ns2:consumerId>
             <ns2:completionCode>100</ns2:completionCode>
          </serverHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Faulted you sent -1 and -1</faultstring>
         <detail>
             <faultResponse xmlns:ns2="http://kp.web.com/schema/" xmlns="http://kp.web.com/Shared/schema/">400</faultResponse>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can I use holder or is there any solution. I can't use interceptor because I need to send the consumer Id back. In interceptor I will not have request details.

Comment: What do you mean interceptors? Can you get link.

Comment: @frostjogla The link gives details about interceptors http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SOAP Message Handlers and Handler Chains](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html). Another way do it use [Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).
I use Handler Chains for modify SOAP header.

This [link](http://informatictips.blogspot.pt/2013/09/using-message-handler-to-alter-soap.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But how do I pass on the soap request data to out bound handler?

Comment: Probably fastest(thought looks like a hack) solution would be to embed your information in SOAP fault body and leave it to handler to modify headers and/or body.

Comment: @ArunasJunevicius Thanks for your suggestion. I was thinking something of similar kind. Rather I was thinking to avoid fault response and in success message add a tag with completion status and error message tag if there is any error I would add errormessage tag in my header and send.

Comment: @KaPra As a rule of thumb I would use SAOP fault where ever it's appropriate and avoid error messages in regular SOAP responses(ironically due to need to integrate with legacy systems we have company policy not to ever throw SOAP faults). Problem is that to keep WS contract consistent every error should be caught and returned as normal SOAP response and for starters that's impossible since JAX-WS runtime might throw SOAP fault. Anyways choose best solution that suites your situation.

Comment: @ArunasJunevicius Yep well said. Thanks for input

Answer (score 1):

You can still use an interceptor. There are two ways you can get the data you need from the interceptor:

1) In you business logic, if you have a WebServiceContext injected in (@Resource), you can set properties on that that you should be able to pick up later from the message.  (or from the message.getExchange().getInMessage())

2) From the message, you can get the Exchange and then get the inMessage.  From that message you can get the contents that were unmarshalled (inMessage.getContent(List.class)) and passed into your class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh Thanks........ I had used getExchange in inbound chain, but didn't expect it to be available for outbound chain. Thanks for figuring it out. I found that header or multiple part was supported earlier but was discontinued recently. from the link http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap:fault it says only one part is allowed. Then how we to keep a track request(JMS way with message id). Was there any specific reason to make it one fault. From consumer code perspective I can understand the difficulty if we have multiple parts. Other than that I don't find any issue